# why in vue object, this line only need half tag 'template: "<App/>" '

Tags: vue.js

when I use the vue webpack template, I found the code like this,

```js
/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>', // <--
  components: { App }
})
```

I know what this means, I just wondering why here only need half tag? is this a abbreviation? I checked the vue js  official document and haven't find any clue.

Comment: It's exactly the same as `template: '<App></App>'`

Answer (score 0):

It's short for

```
<App></App>
```

It only works in string templates (`template: '....'` or `.vue` files), not in in-DOM templates in your .html page.

The reason is that this short form isn't valid HTML after the latest specification (these self-closing elements existed in earlier versions of the HTML spec, though, i.e. `<img src="http://..."/>`)

Since string templates are never touched by the browser's DOM engine, we can allow this shortcut in those.